# Assign AJAX call to a global variable

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have the following code from a question ([How to pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript?rq=1)):

```
<!-- snip -->
<script>
    function reqListener () {
      console.log(this.responseText);
    }

    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest(); //New request object
    oReq.onload = function() {
        //This is where you handle what to do with the response.
        //The actual data is found on this.responseText
        alert(this.responseText); //Will alert: 42
    };
    oReq.open("get", "get-data.php", true);
    //                               ^ Don't block the rest of the execution.
    //                                 Don't wait until the request finishes to 
    //                                 continue.
    oReq.send();
</script>
<!-- snip -->
```

What I need is to pass `this.responseText` into a global variable named "result" like this:

```
<script>
var result;

    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.onload = function getData() {
        result = this.responseText;
    };
    oReq.open("get", "data.php", true);
    oReq.send();


    document.write(result);
</script>
```

The code does get the data from data.php, however I get a "hoisting" issue, any idea on how to make pass that result into a global variable?

Comment: You cannot pass variables into global scope like that because AJAX is asynchronous. The `document.write` like happens *before* the result is returned. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/

Comment: Jay is correct you can however pass the result value upon successful completion of your ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, it's not a hoisting issue, the issue is that you're trying to use `result` before the XHR call has returned data. You can get your current code to work, simply by moving the reference to `result` inside of the `oReq.onload` callback:

```
var result;
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.onload = function getData() {
    result = this.responseText;
    console.log(result);
};
oReq.open("get", "data.php", true);
oReq.send();
```

Then just update whatever part of your app needs the data there, instead of logging it to the console.